# proper use of auth.login_required in 'flask peewee'

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I have a custom admin class. HOw auth.login_required be used...Simply using @auth.login_required as a decorator is not helping. My code snippet

## my_model.py

```
class User(db.Model, BaseUser):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()
    email = CharField(default='')
    active = BooleanField(default=False)
    #...other fields

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

## auth.py

```
class CustomAuth(Auth):
    def get_user_model(self):
        return User

    def get_model_admin(self):
        return UserAdmin

# instantiate custom auth
auth = CustomAuth(app, db, user_model=User)
```

## usuage

```
@some_url.route('/some_url')
@auth.login_required # ITS NOT WORKIN
def some_url():
    return "test url"
```

Comment: What do you mean not working?  Do you have an error, does it let every request through?

Comment: I dint found any particular error though. And lets user to pass through. Even not logged in.
I can view url localhost://homepage/some_url without login.

Did I missed something to initialize auth here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@some_url.route('/some_url')
@auth.login_required # ITS NOT WORKIN
def some_url():
    user = auth.get_logged_in_user()
    return "test url"
```